# Unable to link role for portlet [portletname] with role-name [rolename] liferay 6.1

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

when I deploy my portlet on liferay 6.1.2 , this errors appears:

```
01:57:10,382 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][PortletImpl:2253] Unable to link role for portlet [numberauctionmenu_WAR_numberauctionportlet] with role-name [power-user] because role-link is null
01:57:10,382 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][PortletImpl:2253] Unable to link role for portlet [numberauctionmenu_WAR_numberauctionportlet] with role-name [administrator] because role-link is null
01:57:10,382 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][PortletImpl:2253] Unable to link role for portlet [numberauctionmenu_WAR_numberauctionportlet] with role-name [guest] because role-link is null
01:57:10,382 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][PortletImpl:2253] Unable to link role for portlet [numberauctionmenu_WAR_numberauctionportlet] with role-name [user] because role-link is null
```

but my portlet works without bug...
what is the solution?

Comment: Doesn't sound tragic - you might want to look at your portlet.xml for the role mapping mentioned there and experiment. If you expect an actual answer here, please provide a [mcve] with steps to reproduce: You're asking for debugging help without giving us a clue what to debug. Also: Upgrade to get the recent security fixes. Your version is ~7y old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my liferay-portlet.xml I have:

```
<role-mapper>
<role-name>administrator</role-name>
<role-link>Administrator</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
<role-name>guest</role-name>
<role-link>Guest</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
<role-name>power-user</role-name>
<role-link>Power User</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
<role-name>user</role-name>
<role-link>User</role-link>
</role-mapper>
```